# My gravatar is not visible on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, gravatar, profile-picture

I have added an avatar in Gravatar before 2 months and still not visible on Stack Overflow. I have also selected it. When I go to gravatar and see , it is selected but still no luck. Please help.

Comment: Did you try to upload your profile picture by [a new way](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/announcing-a-new-way-to-change-your-profile-picture/)?

Comment: @hims056 yeah tried different ways with different images with different resolutions..

Comment: Maybe since you entered an invalid HTTP URL in your profile (instead of leaving it empty) this somehow stops the image from being correctly drawn, too?

Comment: @UweKeim How would that work? The Gravatar doesn't depend on the URL (rather on the email address used for it), does it?

Comment: @Bart This was just some wild guessing

Comment: I can see your gravatar just fine. What you see when browsing [directly to it](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d127b96b1cea217ae2627e1b7eb863f8?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG)?

Comment: I have changed it to my photo ut it doesn't work? It still shows default one..

Comment: Have you logged into Gravatar to make it use the uploaded photo? Are you using the same email address there as the one registered here?

Comment: @Oded Yeah..got it solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved by Stackoverflow itself..!! Actually, Stackoverflow has the option to upload the profile pic at the same place only and also to Gravatar. I selected the prior one.